# Which kind of Access Token do I use to scrape Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Assuming I [satisfy the criteria to scrape FB legally](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92887/1066) which [type of Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) do I use when issuing the requests?

- User Access Token
- App Access Token
- Page Access Token
- Client Token

I'm using a typically configuration to scrape, a server running a daemon in cron. Ideally, it'd be un-associated with my personal FB account. I'm just trying to get information about user-specified public page's public events: location, title, description, start_time and end_time.

If I want to make the daemon not-specific to my personal account, or a page I need a client token, or an app token? But, unlike the app token the client token doesn't require OAuth? Which is what I want. The daemon will run on a secure server, so the secret won't be discoverable. Is that correct? Is the Client Access Token the best for my use case?

Comment: The scraping policy has nothing to do with the API. If you using the API you need to folow https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: I'm not asking about the scraping policy. I'm asking about the API.

Comment: @WizKid if you have any questions, feel free to ask. I'm just unclear at all how that comment is relevant.

Comment: @WizKid Seeing as how I got the exact answer I was looking for below, from Niraj, would you mind reading it and telling me why you object to the question?

Comment: You said in your post that you satisfy the scaping policy. The link you gave to link to the same link I gave. The post say:
"You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission".

Comment: No, I didn't say I satisfy it. I said, I'm applying for it for per [this agreement](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos.php). I want to make sure what I want to do is possible before spending too much time pursing it. This is rather routine in the evaluation process. Normally, with a commercial company, you sign an NDA, play, and then negotiate a contract. I've started the agreement, and I'm wanting to play and learn.

Comment: Scraping you do without access token.

Comment: So your objection is to using the term "scraping" for accessing data in an yet-unapproved fashion through the graph api with an access token? call it what you want, I don't care much.. Edit the question. You could have just said it was a terminology problem.

Comment: Impossible to answer the question without know what data you are getting and why

Comment: *"I'm just trying to get information about user-specified public page's public events: location, title, description, start_time and end_time."*

Answer (score 6):

If you are scraping public pages with no interest in user data or information, all you need is the app access token. This will give you access to any publicly available info such as pages, events etc.

The easiest way to use an app access token is to append the App ID and App Secret as follows: `app_id|app_secret`

You can then use to access a public page, e.g.:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/events?access_token=app_id|app_secret
```

There is also no need to ever refresh or update the app access token unless you reset the app secret.

Comment: So the app access token is better than a client access token? Very cool. This is perhaps *exactly* what I was looking for.

Comment: I have verified this works. Thanks for the help. Enjoy the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to learn what data you can access with which token(s) and permissions is Facebook's graph explorer tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

As far as which token to use, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ suggests:

- Any access token can be used to retrieve events with privacy set to OPEN.
- A user access token with user_events permission can be used to retrieve any events that are visible to that person.
- An app or page token can be used to retrieve any events that were created by that app or page.

Comment: I've updated the question to be clear-er (hopefully)